# Delphi 11, TDBCheckbox onClick event does not trigger on dataset cancel

Tags: delphi

upon migrating from D10.3 to D11.3, I noticed that toggling a TDBCheckbox and then cancelling the dataset operation, undoes the toggling but without triggering the onClick event.
in the onClick event, I'm supposed to show/hide it components based on whether the checkbox is clicked or not.

now, after pressing cancel, the visibility of those components is not being altered anymore.

I've tried to trigger other events of the TDBCheckbox, also tried to override the SetChecked and Toggle, none of which did trigger.
this is because at Delphi VCL level, changes were made introducing a flag "ClicksDisabled", precisely preventing what used to work on previous delphi versions.

any ideas what can be done to recover the old behavior, hopefully without having to alter every checkbox behavior in the application?

Comment: This change was necessary to have a similar behavior in `TDBCheckBox` as it has already been before for `TCheckBox`.

Comment: Take a look at TDataSource.OnDataChange. It would be used in addition to your current OnClick since it does not fire until the user moves off a field edit control or when a whole record event occurs like cancel.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the OnDataChange event because if I have a dozen checkboxes on a form, each time anything changes, the code for all the checkboxes would execute. let alone having to modify the behavior in a few hundred forms before being able to upgrade. @uweraabe you mean TCheckboxes checked programmatically did not trigger the onClick event? somehow this does sound familiar

Comment: The corresponding QP issue is https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31489

Comment: @UweRaabe checking again, on Delphi 11, programmatically toggling the "Checked" property of a T(nonDB)Checkbox IS in fact triggering its onClick event.  So I'm confused now what the QP issue is referring to...

Comment: The point is that one can use `ClicksDisabled` to avoid that behavior.

Comment: got it thanks @uwe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by @uwe above, this change was intentional so the TDBCheckbox behaves the same as TCheckbox: that is, a programmatic change of value would not trigger the OnClick event.

The implementation did not offer a way to override a method to revert to an older behavior, nor did it offer an OnChange event **(why should TCheckbox not have an OnChange event?)**.

The proposed solution of moving the code from the TDBCheckbox's OnClick event, to the TDataSource.OnDataChange event is not particularly exciting either, for the following reasons:

- forms with dozens of checkboxes would now regroup all their OnClick code into another component's OnDataChange (yay, OOP!)
- having fun chasing 1000+ checkboxes around the project and altering their implementation, is a long, tedious and error-prone task, likely to introduce more bugs along the way than improving the state of the code.

Instead, defining a new event: `FMyOnChange: TNotifyEvent;`, and in the object inspector, simply move the implementation from OnClick -> MyOnChange, which gets executed in the `WndProc` override below:

```
procedure TMyDBCheckBox.WndProc (var Message: TMessage); // overridden
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    BM_SETCHECK: // passed when the checkbox is toggled, be it on cancel, on scroll or on click
    begin
      if Assigned (FMyOnChange) then
        FMyOnChange (Self);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The above seemed to work whenever the TMyDBCheckbox goes from `unchecked -> checked`, and vice versa, on dataset scroll, dataset cancel, or user-click.

At least, while waiting for Embarcadero to offer a native OnChange event (and hopefully avoid breaking backward compatibility without providing functioning and reasonable alternatives).